# Using XCom with a BashOperator: Pushing multi-line sdout output to other tasks?

Tags: airflow

According to the documentation, "`If xcom_push is True`, the last line written to `stdout` will also be pushed to an **XCom** when the bash command completes."

However, I need to return a multi-line string that results from a **python script** being executed from the terminal. I would like to subsequently use this string in an **EmailOperator**.

So my question is: is it possible to push more than the last line via **xcom_push**? Ideally, it would be arbitrarily long.  I would really appreciate your help, thanks!

EDIT: I have gotten around this problem by using a PythonOperator and calling the script, but I'm still curious if it's possible to push multi-line data to XCom from a BashOperator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As clearly stated in the [source code](https://airflow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/_modules/airflow/operators/bash_operator.html), only the **last** line of the BashOperator is being pushed if `xcom_push = True`.

```
 :param xcom_push: If xcom_push is True, the last line written to stdout
        will also be pushed to an XCom when the bash command completes.
```

However, you could easily create a custom operator inheriting from the BashOperator and implement the double `xcom_push`.

See the [plugins](https://airflow.apache.org/plugins.html) doc on how to build custom operators with Airflow plugins.